# Is it possible to have a copy constructible class that holds a std::unique_ptr<Base> avoiding slicing without Base exposing a "clone" function?

Tags: c++11, copy-constructor, smart-pointers, move-semantics, deep-copy

Is there a way to write a copy-constructor for a class (say, `Copyable`, that holds a `std::unique_ptr` to a `Base` class (but really is storing `Derived` objects.

A quick test shows the expected slicing occurs, because `Copyable` doesn't know the real type it's holding. So I suppose a `clone` method is needed, but I'm wondering if there is a way to let the compiler handle this in some better way?

The slicing code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
struct Base
{
  Base(int i = 0) : i(i) {}
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  int i;
  virtual int f() { return i; }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  Derived() = default;
  virtual int f() override { return 42; }
};

struct Copyable
{
  Copyable(std::unique_ptr<Base>&& base) : data(std::move(base)) {}
  Copyable(const Copyable& other)
  {
    data = std::make_unique<Base>(*other.data);
  }
  std::unique_ptr<Base> data;
};

int main()
{
  Copyable c(std::make_unique<Derived>());
  Copyable c_copy = c;

  std::cout << c_copy.data->f() << '\n';
}
```

The `clone` code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
struct Base
{
  Base(int i = 0) : i(i) {}
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  int i;
  virtual int f() { return i; }

  virtual Base* clone() { return new Base(i); }
};

struct Derived : Base
{
  Derived() = default;
  virtual int f() override { return 42; }

  virtual Derived* clone() override { return new Derived(); }

};

struct Copyable
{
  Copyable(std::unique_ptr<Base>&& base) : data(std::move(base)) {}
  Copyable(const Copyable& other)
  {
    data.reset(other.data->clone());
  }
  std::unique_ptr<Base> data;
};

int main()
{
  Copyable c(std::make_unique<Derived>());
  Copyable c_copy = c;

  std::cout << c_copy.data->f() << '\n';
}
```

Obviously the clone code works. Thing is, there's some things in it I'd like to avoid:

1. raw `new`.
2. a random function that needs to be part of the interface.
3. This function returns a raw pointer.
4. Every user of this class that wants to be copyable needs to call this function.

So, is there a "clean" alternative?

Note I want to use smart pointers for all the obvious reasons, I just need a deep copying `std::unique_ptr`. Something like `std::copyable_unique_ptr`, combining optional move semantics with a deep copying copy constructor. Is this the cleanest way? Or does that only add the the confusion?

Comment: A `std::copyable_unique_ptr` makes no sense. Having a `std::unique_ptr` that points to a clonable object makes a little more sense. What you have is probably the best way. There are a couple of points though: The copy-constructor is a constructor, so it can have a member initialize list. The `clone` functions should invoke the copy-constructor, copying `*this`. And the `clone` function in the derived class should return a pointer to the base class.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How does a `copyable_unique_ptr` make no sense? There are a lot of scenarios where you both want to move and copy data, each when you need them. Granted, you'll need to be careful with `std::move`, but the impossibility of copying a move-only type without dirtying the interface seems to imply this is a sane solution.

Comment: @rubenvb The dangers of copy constructors being called when the user isn't expecting it is a big part of why `auto_ptr` was deprecated. The effect would be slightly less bad with a `copyable_unique_ptr`, but it would still be bad. A `clonable_unique_ptr` (or `clone_ptr` as in Deduplicator's answer) that doesn't provide a copy constructor, but does provide a `clone()` member function, achieves what you hoped to achieve with `copyable_unique_ptr`, but without the danger.

Comment: The danger of a deep copy happening instead of a move? I prefer the default copy/move constuctor generation of classes with a `copyiable_unique_ptr` over a separate clone function. But I agree there is a tradeoff.

Comment: Hmm, it seems impossible to have a `copyable_unique_ptr<Base>` properly create a copy when its pointer is actually `Derived`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly create a `clone_ptr`-class for any object you know statically how to clone.

It would hold a pointer to the object, and a pointer to a function for cloning said object, probably from converting a stateless lambda.